# AngularJs filter:$viewValue is not handling html escaping

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you type A in the box, you'll see:

1. Alabama is missing the text in the bracket
2. Alaska is fine
3. Arizona displays fine but once selected shows as `&lt;` and
   `&gt;`

Any idea on how to prevent filter from sanitizing or (best) use proper encoding and decoding of html characters?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZjPWe/64/

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="row-fluid">
        <form class="row-fluid">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.selected = '';
    $scope.states = ['Alabama <Where is this>', 'Alaska [this is ok]', 'Arizona &lt;Select Me&gt;'];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One not-so-beautiful way to solve this issue is to apply filters to sanitize your array elements, and then unsanitize them when selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/pwu0r81m/

```
$scope.$watch('selected', function() {
    $scope.selected = $scope.selected.replace(new RegExp('&lt;', 'g'), '<').replace(new RegExp('&gt;', 'g'), '>');
});

angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('sanitizer', function(){
        return function (items) {
            var filtered = [];
            angular.forEach(items, function(item){
                filtered.push(item.replace(new RegExp('<', 'g'), '&lt;').replace(new RegExp(">", 'g'), "&gt;"));
            });
            return filtered;
        }
    });
```